# SAS Macro: dereferencing a macro variable in the name of a column name of a dataset

Tags: dataset, sas

In SAS

dereferencing this does not work:

```
data TempTemp2&j. (keep=ITEM_CRT Product_CRT Product_GROUP Reality_&MonthDataInputBalsave_2024 Closing_01_2024); * drop all irrelevant variables;
```

while this does work:

```
data TempTemp2&j. (keep=ITEM_CRT Product_CRT Product_GROUP Reality_&ClosingThisMonth._&ClosingThisYear. ); * drop all irrelevant variables;
```

Any idea why? Numerical/character related?

```
%let ClosingThisMonth = 03;
%let ClosingThisYear = 2024;
*debugging;
%let Month = 03; *currently use one month BEFORE the month you want to do the closing for;
%let Year = 2024;

/* because indexing does not work in the retarded SAS dataset */
/*  renaming the relevant variables would actually make more sense but I tried for 2 hours and then I gave up*/
*calculate the previous month (and year);
%macro SubtractOneMonth;
    
    %if &ClosingThisMonth. = 01 %then %do;
        %let MonthDataInputBalsave = 12;
        %let YearDataInputBalsave = %eval(&ClosingThisYear - 1); /* add zero before single digit somehow */
    %end;
    %else %do;
        %let MonthDataInputBalsave = %eval(&ClosingThisMonth - 1);
        %let MonthDataInputBalsave = %sysfunc(putn(&MonthDataInputBalsave, z2.));
        %put MonthDataInputBalsave: &MonthDataInputBalsave;
        %let YearDataInputBalsave = &ClosingThisYear;
    %end;

    /* Optional: Print the result */
    %put Previous Month: &ClosingThisMonthMinusOneWithZero., Year: &YearDataInputBalsave.;
    
%mend;
%SubtractOneMonth;
```